# Efficient database design for multiple price based on quantity and attribute

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a data sample for products with different prices depending on quantity and attributes. The price might be updated occasionally (not too frequently).

```
PID | Name                | Type  | Colour  | Colour Print | Quantity: 1 to 149 |   150 to 199| 200 to 249 |250 to 499
1   |White ABC Product    |ABC    |White    |1CP           |2.34|2.07   |1.82|1.51
2   |White ABC Product    |ABC    |White    |2CP           |2.6 |2.31   |1.97|1.62
3   |White ABC Product    |ABC    |White    |3CP          |2.86|2.55|2.14|1.77
7   |Red ABC Product      |ABC    |Red      |1CP           |2.39|2.12|1.87|1.56
8   |Red ABC Product      |ABC    |Red      |2CP           |2.65|2.36|2.02|1.67
9   |Red ABC Product      |ABC    |Red      |3CP           |2.91|2.6|2.19|1.82
12  |White XYZ Product    |XYZ    |White    |1CP           |2.69|2.38|2.09|1.74
13  |White XYZ Product    |XYZ    |White    |2CP           |2.69|2.38|2.09|1.74
14  |White XYZ Product    |XYZ    |White    |3CP           |3.29|2.93|2.46|2.04
18  |Emerald  XYZ Product |XYZ    |Emerald  |1CP           |2.74|2.43|2.14  |1.79   
19  |Emerald  XYZ Product |XYZ    |Emerald  |2CP           |3.04|2.71|2.32  |1.91   
20  |Emerald  XYZ Product |XYZ    |Emerald  |3CP           |3.34|2.98|2.51  |2.09
```

So basically, I can design the database as the same structure as the above data sample and dump all data into the table (a lot of repetition) or I can do something like this:

```
Product Table:
---------
--Product id
--Product name {ABC, XYZ, PQR...so on}


Colour Table:
-------
--Colour id
--Colour value {white, red, emerald, and so on}

Colour Print Table 
--------
--Colour print id
--Colour print value {1CP, 2CP, 3CP}

Quantity Table
--------
--Quantity id
--Quantity value {1-149, 150-199, 200-249,250-499}

Price Table
-------
--Price id
--Product id
--Colour id
--Colour Print id
--Quantity id
--Price
```

So the price table will look something like this:

```
Price table                 
price id |  product id |colour id | quantity id | colourprint id |  price
1        | 1           |1         | 1           |1               |2.34
2        | 1           |1         | 2           |1               |2.07
3        | 1           |1         | 3           |1               |1.82
4        | 1           |1         | 4           |1               |1.51
5        | 1           |1         | 1           |2               |2.6
6        | 1           |1         | 2           |2               |2.31
7        | 1           |1         | 3           |2               |1.97
8        | 1           |1         | 4           |2               |1.62
9        | 1           |1         | 1           |3               |2.86
```

Price is displayed to the user when they choose the options based on type of product, colour, colour print and quantity.

New products might also be added in the future. I'm looking to design the database in the most efficient way.

I find the first option easier to implement but not sure if it's the most efficient or if it's even correct.

Your input would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: On a super high level everything looks to be 1-many?

Comment: The second option looks closer to me, but it seems that the schema might benefit from further normalisation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many rows do you have now?  If less than 10 million, why bother making the change?  Do you ever need to change all "emerald" to "green"?  There is such a thing as "over-normalization".

If you are concerned about space, each of these "normalization" tables could be avoided by using `ENUM` such as

```
quantity ENUM('1-149', '150-199', '200-249', '250-499')
```

which would take 1 byte.  However, I would not use ENUM for some list that is likely to change frequently, or that has more than, say, 20 values.  (The actual limit is much higher.)

If you do go with normalization, use either `TINYINT UNSIGNED` (1 byte, 0..255) or `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (2 bytes, 0..65K).

If you do normalize and want to find all "emerald & XYZ" items, the query will be messy and slow.

Please provide the likely `SELECTs` (based on whatever is convenient) so we can critique it further.